# How take two database lists in the same page?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I create one controle to take menu itens in my database, but now i need list itens in the same page.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class ControllerPageViews extends Controller {

    public function home(){
        $menus = DB::select('select * from menus'); 
        return view('index')->with('menus', $menus);
    }

    public function comofunciona(){
        $menus = DB::select('select * from menus'); 
        return view('como-funciona')->with('menus', $menus);
    }

    public function especialidades(){
        $menus = DB::select('select * from menus'); 
        return view('especialidades')->with('menus', $menus);
    }

    public function exames(){
        $menus = DB::select('select * from menus'); 
        return view('exames')->with('menus', $menus);
    }

    public function medicamentos(){
        $menus = DB::select('select * from menus'); 
        return view('medicamentos')->with('menus', $menus);
    }

    public function solicitarconsulta(){
        $menus = DB::select('select * from menus'); 
        return view('solicitar-consulta')->with('menus', $menus);
    }

    public function contatos(){
        $menus = DB::select('select * from menus'); 
        return view('contatos')->with('menus', $menus);
    }   
}
```

I go use elloquent after, but now, is possible import 2 lists in the same page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use compact instead

```
public function contatos(){
$menus = DB::select('select * from menus'); 
$menus2 = DB::select('select * from menus2'); 
return view('contatos',compact('menus','menus2'));
}
```

and then on the view:

```
@foreach($menus as $menu)
{{ $menu->field_name }}
@endforeach

@foreach($menus2 as $menu2)
{{ $menu2->field_name }}
@endforeach
```